# What does numberVar <varname> in a CrystalReport formula do?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

What does the following in a Crystal Report formula do?

```
whilePrintingRecords;
numberVar recLast;
recLast;
```

I can see that this executes while printing records and returns the value of `recLast`. But what does `numberVar recLast` do? Looks like just declaring a variable but then what is this achieving?

I found this in a Formula Field named `checkFooter`.

Answer (score 0):

It declares the variable `recLast` as a `numberVar`.

If `recLast` has been declared in another formula that has been evaluated before, this line is needed to (re-)use it in this formula.

For example if one would evaluate the number, like e.g.:

```
If recLast > 100 Then do something...
```

If the code you posted is the whole code in this formula, then the last line is superfluous because
`numberVar recLast;` will return the value too if it's the the last line in the formula:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numberVar recLast;
```